# How do I add multiple arrays into an unknown size matrix using for loop in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fft

I have an accelerometer sensor reading for x,y and z axis and I want to pass it to fft function.
The sensor reading are stored in *(3xN)* matrix and I would like to input each row vector(in this case 3 row vector) into fft function and store the output in *(3xM)* matrix. The problem is I dont know the size of *M* or to put it simply, how do I stored the result of fft into an unknown size matrix?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq

a = np.linspace(1,30,30).reshape(3,10) 

yf = []
axis = [0,1,2]

for ii in axis:
   yf[ii,:] = rfft(a[ii,:])
   #yf[ii][:] = rfft(a[ii,:])  #is this way in the right direction?
```

I got the error *"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"*. How do I initialize this unknown matrix and what is the right way to solve my problems.

Hope someone could help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `yf` is a *list*, as such it can't be indexed with a *tuple* like a NumPy array can (`yf[ii,:]`).

- You could instead append the values:

  ```
  yf = []
  for ii in axis:
     yf.append(rfft(a[ii,:]))
  ```

  If necessary, you can then convert to it to a NumPy array with `yf = np.array(yf)`.
- Or prepare an empty *complex* NumPy array beforehand:

  ```
  yf = np.empty((3,6), dtype=complex)
  for ii in axis:
     yf[ii] = rfft(a[ii])
  ```

  Note: you can index `yf` and `a` with `ii` directly, no need for `ii, :`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
firstrow=[]
secondrow=[]
thirdrow=[]
firstrow.append(X_rslt)
secondrow.append(Y_rslt)
thirdrow.append(Z_rslt)
basearray=[]
basearray.append(firstrow)
basearray.append(secondrow)
basearray.appen(thirdrow)
```

Comment: firstrow,secondrow,thirdrow represent vectors X,Y,Z

Comment: basearray : list contain on three array that represent vectors

Comment: in python language you don't need to specify size of arrray

Comment: if you want to deal with index in retrive try it : for i in range(0,len(basearray)):firstrow=basearray[i]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
yf = np.apply_along_axis(rfft, 0, a)
```